# Angular material mat tab group in hidden container does not show overflow buttons unless selected tab is clicked

Tags: angular, tabs, angular-material

As mentioned in the [link](https://github.com/angular/components/issues/14462), in angular material tabs the ink bar does not show selection in header properly, which can be resolved with a workaround by using a view child  as shown in the example at [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/realighinkbar-example).

But if you are having overflow as shown in the example above the next and previous buttons only come on selecting the particular tab.

How can I handle the issue, taking the above example as reference.

Image 1: Active tab not clicked
[image]

Image 2: Active tab clicked 
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A workaround I found to make my ink bar update and pagination occur correctly was to add a method to manually update header on resize,open and close events of my hidden container

```
function updateTabHeader() {
 this.matTabGroupReference._tabHeader.updatePagination();
 this.matTabGroupReference.realignInkbar();
}
```

matTabGroupReference is a refernce to mat-tabs-group component

Comment: You need to retype:
    (this.matTab._tabHeader as MatPaginatedTabHeader).updatePagination();